# make code java 1.6 compatible (try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6)

Tags: java, java-6

I have the following code which is java 1.7 compatible, however, I need it to be compatible with java 1.6. currently I get the following error for this code: `try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6`

the code looks like this:

```
    try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, input.getModel())) {
        // Some other code
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            // do something
        }
        return something;
    }
```

what do I need to change in order to make it work with java 1.6?

Comment: Side note: Please note that Oracle Java SE 6 and now even Oracle Java SE 7 reached EoL. So if you're using the implementation from Oracle and don't have according support contracts then it's strongly recommended to upgrade to Java SE 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The real answer:**

The real answer here is **use Java 7 or 8**. Java 6 is very old. Java 7 came out *four years* ago; Java 8, almost a year and a half.

Only keep reading if there's a *very, very good* reason you can't do that. :-)

**TL;DR**

That ***specific*** example can be simply:

```
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, input.getModel());
Throwable thrown = null;
try {
    // Some other code
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        // do something
    }
    return something;
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    thrown = t; // Remember we're handling an exception
    throw t;
}
finally {
    try {
        qexec.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        if (thrown == null) {
            // Not handling an exception, we can rethrow
            throw t;
        }
        else {
            // Log it or something, you can't allow it to
            // throw because there's *already* an exception
            // being thrown and you'll hide it. This is why
            // Java 7 added Throwable#addSuppressed.
        }
    }
}
```

But that's because it's a very simple case. If there were any other resources that needed closing (`results`, for instance?) or you were handling some exceptions in the code itself, it would be more complicated.

The more general form is;

```
SomeResource r1 = null;
Throwable thrown = null;
try {
    r1 = new SomeResource();

    SomeOtherResource r2 = null;
    try {
        r2 = new SomeOtherResource();
        // use them
        return something;
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        thrown = t; // Remember we're handling an exception
        throw t;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            r2.close();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            if (thrown == null) {
                // Not handling an exception, we can rethrow
                throw t;
            }
            else {
                // Log it or something, you can't allow it to
                // throw because there's *already* an exception
                // being thrown and you'll hide it. This is why
                // Java 7 added Throwable#addSuppressed.
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    thrown = t; // Remember we're handling an exception
    throw t;
}
finally {
    try {
        r1.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        if (thrown == null) {
            // Not handling an exception, we can rethrow
            throw t;
        }
        else {
            // Log it or something
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want some utility library functions to help with this, it's a **lot** of boilerplate otherwise. I used to have things that did "silent" closes for the case where I knew an exception was already happening.

---

Details: This is covered by [§14.20.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) and its subsections:

A simple `try-with-resources`:

```
try ({VariableModifier} R Identifier = Expression ...)
    Block
```

translates to:

```
{
    final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
    Throwable #primaryExc = null;

    try ResourceSpecification_tail
        Block
    catch (Throwable #t) {
        #primaryExc = #t;
        throw #t;
    } finally {
        if (Identifier != null) {
            if (#primaryExc != null) {
                try {
                    Identifier.close();
                } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                    #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                }
            } else {
                Identifier.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to remove the `addSuppressed` part as `Throwable` didn't have that in JDK6.

An extended `try-with-resources`:

```
try ResourceSpecification
    Block
[Catches]
[Finally]
```

translates to:

```
try {
    try ResourceSpecification
        Block
}
[Catches]
[Finally]
```

...where that

```
try ResourceSpecification
    Block
```

...is replaced by the big thing that the simple `try-with-resources` turns into, so the whole thing turns into:

```
try {
    {
        final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
        Throwable #primaryExc = null;

        try ResourceSpecification_tail
            Block
        catch (Throwable #t) {
            #primaryExc = #t;
            throw #t;
        } finally {
            if (Identifier != null) {
                if (#primaryExc != null) {
                    try {
                        Identifier.close();
                    } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                        #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                    }
                } else {
                    Identifier.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[Catches]
[Finally]
```

...which is why we love the `try-with-resources` statement so much.

Comment: `try` is used twice in the last snippet, or is it a typo?

Comment: @beta: Nope, that's how it expands. An extended `try-with-resources` converts into an outer `try`/`catch`/`finally` with a simple `try-with-resources` inside it.

Comment: okay, but i thought "try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.6"?

Comment: @beta: Right. As I said in the answer: *"where that [code] ...is replaced by the big thing that the simple try-with-resources turns into"*

Comment: okay, i am sorry but i still dont get what that means for my example code above...

Comment: @beta: You're best off finding some old best-practices articles for resource handling prior to Java 7. I've added an example of how that *specific* code would be modified, and also a slightly more-accessible template. But definitely do more reading on the subject.

Comment: @Puce: As I said in my comment above: *"I guess a more thorough version could allow an exception provided one wasn't already being thrown."* And I was off adding that handling, in fact. :-) Thanks for flagging it up. Man I love not having to worry about that stuff anymore.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The code is now correct. But I don't agree that it's the second exception you **should** suppress. I think it doesn't really matter, but suppressing all but the last takes less code. And it's the idiom most commonly used in the pre try-with-resources era.

Comment: @Puce: Suppressing all but the last is very, very wrong (in my view) -- and I certainly never saw it in production code. Usually, the **first** exception is the important one, and that's what Java 7 gives primacy to, making anything else that happened secondary (suppressed, but added to the suppressed list). An exception on `close` while processing an exception from the `try` block is probably just a knock-on effect of the exception in the `try` block. Much more important to know what *really* went wrong.

Comment: @Puce: But the **real** answer to this question is conspicuous by its absense: Use Java 7 or 8! :-) *(Edit: I've fixed that now)*

Comment: There's quite a few questions about how to do `try-with-resources` in pre-Java 7. Perhaps there should be a reference question with an answer similar to this and perhaps some links to said best practices? (With "Use Java 7+" in a bigger and bolder font)

Comment: @Ordous: :-) Absolutely, if you can find links. In fact, if you can find a good example, probably should mark this question as a duplicate. Don't know if you have a gold Java badge, but if not, ping me if you find one and I can close it a dupe with a single vote.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nah, I don't have access to Mjölnir for Java. I'll have a look around this evening for a good candidate, if I can't find one, I'll think about making one myself.

Comment: for the proposed code above i get `unreported exception java.lang.Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown` for bot `throw t;` statements

Comment: @beta: Ah, yes, the weird and broken hierarchy that is `Throwable`/`Exception`/`RuntimeException`... You'll need to adjust the various catch and throws as appropriate to your situation. Or spend that time upgrading to Java 8. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> what do I need to change in order to make it work with java 1.6?

Try the following code:

```
QueryExecution qexec = null; 
try {
  qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, input.getModel()));
  // Some other code
  while (results.hasNext()) {
      // do something
  }
  return something;
} finally {
    if (qexec != null){
        qexec.close();
    }
}
```

The most imporant part: the streams have to be closed manually in the finally block.

Please note however that Oracle Java SE 6 and now even Oracle Java SE 7 reached EoL. So if you're using the implementation from Oracle and don't have according support contracts then it's strongly recommended to upgrade to Java SE 8

Comment: The code above allows an exception from `close` to completely hide an exception that happened in the `try` block. That's not a good idea. All of the pre-Java 7 handling I saw ensured that `close` exceptions couldn't mask an exception already being thrown, on the basis that it's usually (not always!) the more important one, as the `close` can easily be a by-product of it. In any case, logging is required as a *minimum*, not just silently hiding it.

Comment: Sorry auto-generated message. What I meant was that answers which are just code are discouraged. Please explain why this code answers the question and what the key points are.